# Show that for values of $y \geq 1$, the equation $y^2$cos $x-e^x = 0$ has a solution for $x$ lying in the interval $[0, \pi/2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I started out by rearranging the equation:
$$e^x-y^2 cos x = 0$$
Set $f(x) = e^x-y^2 cos x$, and $k = 0$. By the intermediate value theorem, if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,\pi/2)$, and $f(0) \leq f(\pi/2)$, then $f(0)\leq 0 \leq f(\pi/2) \Rightarrow 0 = f(c)$ for some $c \in [0, \pi/2)$; in other words, the equation has a solution for $x$ lying in $[0, \pi/2)$.

It is easy to observe that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0, \pi/2)$. We know that
$$f(0) = 1-y^2$$
and
$$f(\pi/2) = e^{\pi/2}$$
So for values of $y \geq 1$,
$$f(0)\leq 0 \leq f(\pi/2)$$
which implies
$$0 = f(c)$$
For some $c \in [0, \pi/2)$, and the proof is complete.

Is this proof legitimate? Also, why the open interval? I think it makes no difference in terms of the reasoning.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is mostly correct. To be more clear, you want to separate the $y$ into two cases: $y = 1$, then $f(0) = 0$, thus $x=0$ is indeed a solution. If $y > 1$, then $f(0) = 1 -y^2 < 0, f(\pi/2) = e^{\pi/2} > 0$, then IVT theorem says $f(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (0,\pi/2)$ and $c$ is a solution.

Comment: Thank you! I mentioned that $f(x)$ is continuous intuitively, but if I wanted to prove it, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: $f(x)$ is the difference of two continuous functions, hence is continuous.